# Mediapipe: How to properly dealloc MPPGraph

Tags: mediapipe

It is unclear to me how to properly stop and deallocate the MPPGraph. I created a framework very similar to [this](https://github.com/noppefoxwolf/HandTracker). Every time a dealloc is called in some way this exception is thrown. `Thread 1: Exception: "waitUntilDoneWithError: should not be called on the main thread"`.

I don't know how to not call it in the main thread and was hoping someone had some insight on this.

[Here](https://github.com/sncalvo/MediapipeTest/blob/master/mediapipetest/mediapipetest/MediapipeHandler.swift) you can find the swift code that is calling the mediapipe framework. This example has been created with the framework that can be found [here](https://github.com/noppefoxwolf/HandTracker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone experiencing same issue. This has been addressed [here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/651) and a solution has been proposed.

Edit:
This last bit might be wrong but I used dealloc in this way:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  self.mediapipeGraph.delegate = nil;
  [self.mediapipeGraph cancel];
  // Ignore errors since we're cleaning up.
  [self.mediapipeGraph closeAllInputStreamsWithError:nil];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self.mediapipeGraph waitUntilDoneWithError:nil];
  });
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue, following the solution in the link does not fix the issue. Can you please post your solution here or steps that you might have followed?

Comment: I updated the answer with some code showing how I ended up implementing deallocation

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer, I will try the same